Curl in non-orthogonal coordinates
How can I transform the curl operator into general non-orthogonal coordinates? I have tried to transform its orthogonal expression using the determinant but to no avail. I can't get the same results as using Hodge operators. Thank you very much.
I tried transforming components:
for transformation $\alpha: (x^1,x^2,x^3)\to (q^1,q^2,q^3)$
\begin{align*}
&(\text{rot}\vec F)_k=
\epsilon_{ijk}\frac{\partial F^i(x^l)}{\partial x^j}\circ\alpha
=\epsilon_{ijk}\left\{\frac{\partial }{\partial x^j}\left(\widetilde F^\beta(q^\mu) \cdot  \frac{\partial (x^i\circ\alpha)}{\partial q^\beta}\right)\right\}\circ\alpha\\
=&\epsilon_{ijk}\left\{\frac{\partial }{\partial x^j}\Bigg[\left(\widetilde F^\beta(x^l) \cdot  \frac{\partial (x^i\circ\alpha)}{\partial q^\beta}\right)\circ \alpha^{-1}\Bigg]\right\}\circ\alpha=\\
=&\epsilon_{ijk}\left\{\frac{\partial }{\partial q^\mu}\left[\widetilde F^\beta(x^l) \cdot  \frac{\partial (x^i\circ\alpha)}{\partial q^\beta}\right]\circ \alpha^{-1}\cdot \frac{\partial q^\mu}{\partial x^j}\right\}\circ\alpha=\\
=&\epsilon_{ijk}\frac{\partial }{\partial q^\mu}\left(\widetilde F^\beta(x^j) \cdot  \frac{\partial (x^i\circ\alpha)}{\partial q^\beta}\right)\cdot \frac{\partial q^\mu}{\partial x^j}\circ\alpha
=\\=&
\epsilon_{ijk}\frac{\partial \widetilde F^\beta}{\partial q^\mu}\left(\frac{\partial q^\mu}{\partial x^j}\circ \alpha\right)
\frac{\partial (x^i\circ \alpha)}{\partial q^\beta}
+
\epsilon_{ijk}\widetilde F^\beta \frac{\partial^2(x^i\circ \alpha) }{\partial q^\mu\partial q^\beta} \left(\frac{\partial q^\mu}{\partial x^j}\circ\alpha\right)=\\
=&\epsilon_{ijk}
\Bigg(D_{\alpha^{-1}}\Bigg)^\mu_j
\,\Bigg(\frac{\partial \widetilde F}{\partial q}\Bigg)_\mu^\beta\,
\Bigg(D_\alpha\Bigg)^i_\beta
+
\epsilon_{ijk} \left(\Biggl( \frac{\partial} {\partial q^\mu}D_\alpha\Biggr)_{\beta }^i\,\,\Bigg(
\widetilde F\Bigg)^\beta  \right)_\mu^i\Bigg(D_{\alpha^{-1}}\Bigg)_j^\mu=\\
=&\epsilon_{ijk}
\frac{\partial q^\mu}{\partial x^j}
\frac{\partial \widetilde F^\beta}{\partial q^\mu}
\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial q^\beta}
+
\epsilon_{ijk} 
\frac{\partial^2 x^i} {\partial q^\mu\partial q^\beta}
\widetilde F^\beta
\frac{\partial q^\mu} {\partial x^j}
=\end{align*}
but for simple spherical coordinates
\begin{align*}
...=&\Bigg(\epsilon_{ijk}\Bigg)
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x}\\
\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}&\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}&\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial r}{\partial z}&\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial z}&\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial z}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial \widetilde F^1}{\partial r}&\frac{\partial \widetilde F^2}{\partial r}&\frac{\partial \widetilde F^3}{\partial r}\\
\frac{\partial \widetilde F^1}{\partial \theta}&\frac{\partial \widetilde F^2}{\partial \theta}&\frac{\partial \widetilde F^3}{\partial \theta}\\
\frac{\partial \widetilde F^1}{\partial \varphi}&\frac{\partial \widetilde F^2}{\partial \varphi}&\frac{\partial \widetilde F^3}{\partial \varphi}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}&\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}&\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}\\
\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}&\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}&\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta}\\
\frac{\partial x}{\partial \varphi}&\frac{\partial y}{\partial \varphi}&\frac{\partial z}{\partial \varphi}
\end{pmatrix}
+
\Bigg(\epsilon_{ijk}\Bigg)
\begin{pmatrix}\widetilde F^r&\widetilde F^\theta&\widetilde F^\varphi
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial r^2}&\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial r^2}&\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial r^2}\\
\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial r\partial \theta}&\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial r\partial \theta}&\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial r\partial \theta}\\
\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial r\partial \varphi}&\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial r\partial \varphi}&\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial r\partial \varphi}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\\
\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial r}{\partial z}
\end{pmatrix}
+\\
&+\Bigg(\epsilon_{ijk}\Bigg)
\begin{pmatrix}\widetilde F^r&\widetilde F^\theta&\widetilde F^\varphi
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial\theta\partial r}&\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial\theta\partial r}&\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial\theta\partial r}\\
\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial \theta^2}&\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial \theta^2}&\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial \theta^2}\\
\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial\theta\partial \varphi}&\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial\theta\partial \varphi}&\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial\theta\partial \varphi}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}\\
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial z}
\end{pmatrix}
+\Bigg(\epsilon_{ijk}\Bigg)
\begin{pmatrix}\widetilde F^r&\widetilde F^\theta&\widetilde F^\varphi
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial\varphi\partial r}&\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial\varphi\partial r}&\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial\varphi\partial r}\\
\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial \varphi\partial\theta}&\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial \varphi\partial \theta}&\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial \varphi\partial \theta}\\
\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial \varphi^2}&\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial \varphi^2}&\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial \varphi^2}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x}\\
\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial z}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
the product of Jacobi matrices leads to monstrous matrices.

It's discouraged to offer answers without OP providing an attempt. Do you know any way to start? One thing comes to mind is just use an orthonormal system coupled with a coordinate change operations.

Can you give more details about your attempts and the results you obtained differ from the results you expect? There are formulas for these operators in general coordinates (see here https://www.ijmo.org/vol5/461-WP012.pdf) as well as characterizations in terms of Riemannian metrics but it is difficult to understand what is wrong with your work without more details.

Are you familiar with differential forms and the exterior derivative? This provides a coordinate free framework to compute $\mathrm{curl}\xi=\eta$ by identifying the vector fields $\xi,\eta$ with $1$ and $2$-forms respectively.

I am looking for a calculation without using differential forms, just using classical calculus.

I suppose you'll have to grind through the chain rule by hand then (the only thing differential forms do for you at that point is book keeping anyways). What kind of coordinates do you want? What goes wrong in your attempts so far?

If you want to make your life harder use just classical calculus. It is totally unclear why your matrices contain second partial derivatives. Here is the classical derivation.
